# Prove that: $\{Kf_n \ ; n \in \mathbb N\}$ is equicontinuous

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis

Let $a, b \in \mathbb R$. Let:

$K \in C([a,b]^2)$.

$(f_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a bounded sequence of functions in $C([a,b])$ equipped with $||\cdot||_{\infty}$ the norm of uniform convergence.

$Kf: [a,b] \longrightarrow \mathbb R$, such that: $Kf(x) = \int_a^bK(x,t)f(t)dt$

It is required to prove that $K$ is uniformly continuous and that $F = \{Kf_n\ ; n \in \mathbb N\}$ is equicontinuous on $[a,b]$.

I am okay with how to prove that, but why is it asking to prove just equicontinuity? Isn't it uniformly equicontinuous as well?

As $(f_n)_{n \ge 1}$ is a bounded sequence of functions, then there exists $M > 0$ such that $\forall \ n \in \mathbb N$, $||f_n||_{\infty} \le M$.

Let $\epsilon > 0$. Since $K$ is uniformly continuous on $[a,b]^2$, there exists $\delta > 0$ such that whenever $(u_1,v_1), (u_2,v_2) \in [a,b]^2$ satisfy $\max(|u_1 - u_2|, |v_1 - v_2|) < \delta$, $|K(u_1,v_1) - K(u_2,v_2)| < \frac{\epsilon}{2 \times M \times (b - a)}$.

Let $u,v$ be arbitrary in $[a,b]$, such that $|u - v| < \delta$:

$$|Kf_n(u) - Kf_n(v)| \le \int_a^b |f_n(t)|\times|K(u,t) - K(v,t)|dt \le \int_a^b M\times|K(u,t) - K(v,t)|dt < \int_a^b M \times \frac{\epsilon}{2 \times M \times (b - a)}dt = \frac{\epsilon}{2} < \epsilon$$

Is there something wrong with this?

(Some details were omitted, but I think you got the idea).

Comment: Who is this idiot who downvoted the question? At least explain why.

Comment: I don't know who did that, I upvoted though! Your question is actually a very well-posed first question. You showed effort, that is something that we actually like. :)

Comment: You argument looks good to me. Are there other questions in this problem?

Comment: Thank you Pedro.
@DavideGiraudo: It asks to prove that $(Kf_n)_n$ has a convergent subsequence. We know that $\{Kf_n \ ; n \in \mathbb N\}$ is equibounded and equicontinuous, and $[a.b]^2$ is compact, then by Ascoli-Arzela, the set is relatively compact and the result follows. There are no further questions.

Comment: your argument is correct but what you have shown is the equicontinuity of the family (according to the definition I know). If this problem is from a book other than the one you studied equicontinuity from, then I suggest you to check the definitions of the two texts. Nevertheless, @ BolzWeir, your argument is correct....

Comment: @BolzWeir: Why did you delete your other question on holomorphic functions?